# Run Macro in all worksheets2

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a sheet and I want to keep a specific section and delete the rest unwanted data based on a specific text search.specific text is dynamic.

So based on Activecell using offset I delete the portion above the specific text and want delete the below portion as well. (Say for example row 56-61 only the data I need, will not be same rows in all sheets)

the current code runs for one worksheet and stops in the second sheet

```
Sub Test999()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range
    For Each ws In Worksheets
            Set f = ws.Cells.Find(What:="abc", After:=ActiveCell, 
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    ws.Range(f.Offset(-2, 0), 
ws.Range("A2")).EntireRow.Delete
                    ws.Range(f, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                    ws.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0), 
ws.Range("A500")).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I want to run this code to all worksheets

Comment: Try to activate the worksheet after this line `For Each ws In Worksheets` in that way `ws.Activate`

Comment: @YasserKhalil . i don't think you need to activate a sheet, because you are specifying the sheet in `ws`. And it's always better to avoid the use of `Activate` & `Select`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I suggested that because the OP used Select method in the code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue in the Range Selection.

Also be sure that `ActiveCell` corresponds to the correct cell you want to search from, because activecell can be different in each sheet.

```
Sub Test999()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range

       For Each ws In Worksheets

            'Debug.Print ws.Name

            Set f = ws.Cells.Find(What:="abc", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    ws.Activate
                    ws.Range(f.Offset(-2, 0), ws.Range("A2")).Select
                    ws.Range(f.Offset(-2, 0), ws.Range("A2")).EntireRow.Delete
                    f.Select
                    ws.Range(f, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                    ws.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0), ws.Range("A500")).EntireRow.Delete

            End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: my issue is - not directly offset from the ActiveCell, In a sheet if  "abc" - (f)  is row 50, I have data without blank till 54. So I want to offset 2 rows from Row 54 and delete rest of rows till 500.

Comment: So I have used the code - Selection.End(xlDown).Select

Comment: this is always fixed that data is present for 4 more rows where "abc" is found ?

Comment: Amended code the first one above is not working, i am looking for some support

Comment: Okay @Moras .. Do one thing, try running your Code using F8 and check at every step what exactly is happening in your sheet. and see where the code goes wrong.

Comment: Otherwise if possible, share your worksheet, I will see why it's not Working

Comment: @Moras .. I have made the changes, use the code now. It will work

Comment: Can you check the code got saved? I don't see any change, Macro stops in the second page

Comment: @Moras, not in the File. Here in the Answer, use the Answer.